Access and modify image generator on website
I'm curious if it's possible to modify this generator that exports a png image from user input.
The output image is ultra-low resolution.
I'm wondering if the generator can be modified to output a higher-resolution image. The perfect scenario would be to download the font used in the image or bits of the font and piece them together afterwards.
Here's a high-resolution reference image of the font.
P.S.
I'm only interested in the font. With a high-resolution image, I can trace the characters and make a font out of them, or just get the complete font file if it's obtainable :)

Have you contacted the site operator? It's possible they have a font they'd be willing to share, but we don't have anything more than you!

Compare the font(s) to DIN 1451, but Denmark may not have used that or a derivative

I'm pretty sure it's Tahoma.  Tahoma.ttf
